# Blackbody emission spectrum vs Boltzmann distribution

Tags: electromagnetism, thermodynamics, classical-mechanics, statistical-mechanics, electromagnetic-radiation

In Hydrogen we see certain specific emission spectral lines corresponding to the discrete quantum energy levels of it's single electron. As the material gets up to higher atomic number and more electrons these spectral lines increase in number and cover a wider color/frequency range.
Now if we are talking about blackbody spectrum then I would assume that Hydrogen gas would be a poor blackbody emitter because if heated it releases distinct spectrum colors instead of a more homogeneous spectrum, so if I could make a incandescent filament from hydrogen it would shine less like a blackbody emitter and more like a gas discharge lamp , but filament from tungsten for example shines closer to a perfect blackbody right?

Is that because higher atomic number elements have more electrons and so more electron energy levels so they can have much more spectral emission lines almost filling the visible spectrum with some gaps that are not seen by the eye ?

Also while we are at it , if we take a ideal gas as a blackbody emitter, the gas particles follow the boltzmann distribution bell type curve but blackbody spectrum is always different and not linear, why is that ? is it because some energy levels emit stronger than others due to their difference?
thanks.

Comment: Also https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/256758/how-do-black-bodies-absorb-and-emit-radiation and https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/71503/what-causes-a-black-body-radiation-curve-to-be-continuous